# Prove/Disprove $p(A\mid B, C) = p(A\mid C) ⇒ p(A\mid B) = p(A)$

Tags: probability

I am really struggling with the following problem:

Prove or disprove that: $$p(A\mid B, C) = p(A\mid C) ⇒ p(A\mid B) = p(A).$$

This seams easy to prove or disprove but I simply cannot find the right steps. My approach until now was to use Baye's Theorem:

$$P(A\mid B,C) = \frac{P(C\mid A,B)P(A\mid B)}{P(C\mid B)}$$

Then I would try to change $P(A\mid B)$ with $P(A)$ since this is what the implication says, but I simply cannot find a way to prove or disprove the statement. My intuition was that the statement is true.

$$P(A\mid B,C) = \frac{P(C\mid A,B)P(A)}{P(C\mid B)}$$

Hints would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried swapping the roles of $B$ and $C$ in your middle display equation?  You know you are trying to get a "$P(A\mid C)$", ...

Comment: Thx for the edit Bernard. My problem is probably that I think this equation is true? Because if I change as you said $P(A | B, C) = P(B | A, C)P(A | C)/P(B | C) ≠ P(A | C)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about that:

$P(X=i)=1/6, \forall i\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}, A=\{1\}, B=\{1,2,3\}, C=\{1,2\}$

We get $P(A| B,C)=P(A|C)=1/2$ (because $C\subset B$) but $P(A|B)=1/3\not=1/6 = P(A)$.

So the implication does not hold in general.

Comment: Yes, started to think that something was wrong with my first assumption. Thanks for the example ;)

Comment: But your question reminded me of something funny. Maybe it's something you thought about while thinking about your equation. So, let $X,Y$ be random variables which are independent given a third r.v. $U$ and $X=Y$ a.s. given $U$. That gives you, that $\mathcal{L}(X)=\mathcal{L}(Y)$ is a Dirac-measure :-)

But that is a different story! I'm glad, that we solved your problem!